# Register a PKCS#11 library

Tags: c#, xml, windows-installer, pkcs#11

I am trying to install a PKCS#11 module into Firefox browser via an MSI setup application. 
After doing some search through the internet, I bumped into the 'modutil' tool which has a wide variety of responsibilities especially in my case for = installing/uninstalling the PKCs#11 module to NSS security databases. 
I downloaded the latest source code and built it using MozillaBuild.

Unfortunately, it shows me an error even when I try to create security databases = (3 with .db extension). The error says "Function failed: The certificate/ke= y database is in an old, unsupported format"!.

Does anybody know how I can overcome this issue, and is there any unseen aspect to work with this utility. Also, is there a solution to install/uninstall pkcs#11 module for all user profiles with one common process. 
Finally, is there a better solution to do the task of installation using mysetup. I use WiX Toolset to create MSI setup. -

Comment: please show your research with your question

Comment: i am trying Installing PKCS11 Modules Using nsIPKCS11 and NSS modutil tools.  i have my pkcs dll which should be loaded to library by script or any automation.